# Kendo Grid - can you add row with a popup and edit inline?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is this possible? Right now I have:

```
kendoGrid = gridObj.kendoGrid({
    dataSource: gridDataSource,
    editable: "popup",
});
```

Which works great, but I want the editing to happen inline, and only adding rows in popups, is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean creation using popup and edition using inline?

Comment: OneBai - Ye, that is what I mean!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oops, this is going to be a little tricky. What I'm gonna do is define the grid as editable `inline` by default and then define my own create button, in the handler of my custom create button I temporarily change the `editable` mode to `popup` and then (once popup is open) revert it to `inline`. Something like:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    toolbar: [ 
        {
            // My own version of "Add new record" button, with name **popup**
            text : "Add new record", 
            name: "popup", 
            iconClass: "k-icon k-add"
        }
    ],
    // By default is **inline**
    editable: "inline",
    ...
}).data("kendoGrid");

// Event handler for my **popup** button defined in the grid toolbar
$(".k-grid-popup", grid.element).on("click", function () {
    // Temporarily set editable to "popup"
    grid.options.editable = "popup";
    // Insert row
    grid.addRow();
    // Revert editable to inline
    grid.options.editable = "inline";
});
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/7nj0pxwz/

Comment: So simple, yet so genius!

Comment: Very nice! I'm using Kendo asp.net MVC. Is there any way I can set the name of the template for the popup editor as well?